# How can i write with prallel threads into one Table

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, in-memory-database, in-memory

I am working on a application which is reading a lot of data with parallel threads into one Table.

I'm using Microsoft's SQL Server 2014 with one memory optimized Table and a native compiled stored procedure for writing.

My application reads tons of data (Virtual Trades) into this memory optimized Table :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trades]
(
    [asset_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [trade_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [BNP] [money] NOT NULL,
    [LSP] [money] NULL,
    [expires] [int] NULL,
    [timestamp] [bigint] NULL,
    [currentBid] [money] NULL,
    [startingBid] [money] NULL,
    [pos] [nchar](3) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    [rating] [int] NOT NULL,

INDEX [asset] NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
    [asset_id],
    [BNP]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 32),
    CONSTRAINT [Trades_primaryKey] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
[trade_id]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 64)
)WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON , DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA )
GO
```

The Stored Procedure calculates at every call an average price for the column `BNP` for all rows with the same `asset_id` to find out if the current trade is a very cheap one :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADD_TRADE_]
    @asset int,             -- asset_id
    @trade nchar(12),       -- trade_id
    @BNP int,               -- BuyNowPrice
    @LSP int,               -- LastSellPrice
    @expires nchar(16),     -- expiration in seconds
    @timestamp bigint,  -- current timestamp 
    @currentBid int,        -- current Bid on trade
    @startingBid int,       -- starting Bid on trade
    @pos nchar(3),          -- Player Position
    @rating int,            -- Card Rating
    @MIN_TRADE_CNT int,
    @BUY_PERCENTAGE int,
    @AVG_BNP int
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING, EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH
(
 TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT, LANGUAGE = N'us_english'
)
    --CONFIG

    /* RATING TO COLOR
    DECLARE @BRONZE int = 64
    DECLARE @SILVER int = 74
    */
    /* 1 //// INSERT FRESH TRADES ////////////////////// */
    --TMP VARS
    DECLARE @trade_cnt int = 0
    DECLARE @exists bit = 0

    --CHECK IF TRADE EXISTS
    SELECT  @exists=1
        FROM [dbo].[Trades] 
        WHERE trade_id = @trade
    -- ADD IF NOT
    IF @exists=0
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Trades]
        (asset_id,trade_id,BNP,LSP,expires,timestamp,currentBid,startingBid,pos,rating)
    VALUES(@asset, @trade,@BNP,@LSP,@expires,@timestamp,@currentBid,@startingBid,@pos,@rating)

        //// CHECK IF TRADE IS A GOOD ONE TO BUY ////////////////////
        DECLARE @MIN_BID_PRICE money  = 0
        SELECT @trade_cnt=COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Trades;

        SET @MIN_BID_PRICE = (@AVG_BNP/100) * @BUY_PERCENTAGE

        /// IF YES , ADD TO BID TABLE
        IF @trade_cnt >= @MIN_TRADE_CNT AND @BNP > 0 AND @BNP < @MIN_BID_PRICE 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[Bids](trade_id,bid,max) VALUES(@trade,@BNP,@MIN_BID_PRICE)
        END
    END
END
```

So it not only writes parallel, it also reads parallel.
Now my problem is that some writes get blocked, and i get this error:
`A previous transaction that the current transaction took a dependency on has aborted, and the current transaction can no longer commit.`

If I handle this error and use a retry logic, some of these retries still get blocked up to 10 times and this don't only blocks one specific the thread of the worker it builds up a big stack of threads waiting for their turn to write.

I searched and found a page of msdn where their describe the isolation levels
And I think `read committed` is what I need.
But it seems like I can't use that in a memory optimized table.

What can I change in my code or can I use an alternative DB System for this?

Comment: how about implementing a queue structure?

Comment: Can this be fast enough?
I have to ensure that the calculations can use the newest incoming data.
I can imagine that the queue would be very long and block all my threads

Comment: You wouldn't have any problems with retry, and you could POSS (before reading data) check that the queue is empty? just a suggestion though.

Comment: If I check if the queue is empty. Wouldn't that also block my thread? Because the threads don't do anything else then reading data and calling the stored procedure.

Comment: that way you would be able to get accurate data after all has been added - if you didn't check, you would be reading data which would then be outdated once a record has been added/edited

Comment: I think you need to rethink your design.  It seems that this problem is better handled outside the db accessing memory directly through collections and controlling access through locks or semaphores.  Updates to the db table could be executed async or on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How're you getting your data into your stored procedure? If it's via a .NET application you'd probably be better off creating a `DataTable` in memory for all your columns - including the calculated column and then using the `SqlBulkCopy` class to write all of that data in one go. if you've got too much, you could always break it down into batches.

It's a lot more efficient that trying to write one line at a time!

Comment: Can i write multiple rows with bulk copy into the table? And if yes, what happens if one of the trades already exists (primary key trade_id), will the whole operation stop or the one row just be ignored?

Comment: The whole point of using 'SqlBulkCopy' is to write more than one row at a time. If anything fails e.g. primary key constraint, the whole import should be rolled back. Google search would have answered that!

Comment: As you can see in the stored procedure. Every trade has do proceed a little calculation to determine an average price. Bulk Copy would just help me to fast insert data. My problems are these deadlocks